# Why does the solution for the derivative of the quadratic function on x value, equals the first coefficient on the linear function?

Tags: derivatives, linear-transformations, quadratics, tangent-line

I have the following function
$$() = 2² − 3 − 2$$
and I have to find the angle made by the tangent to this function at
$$  =(1, −3)$$ with the  −axis.

I know the linear function
$$() =  + n$$ and
$$  =(1, −3)$$
so $$(1) =  +  = −3$$
and then to find m there is the derivative of the quadratic $$′() = 4 − 3$$
$$′(1) = 4 − 3 = 1 ⟹ m$$

I assumed that because the derivative and the linear function belong to the same quadratic, they will have the same properties, and that's why we use the derivative.

But why m equals 1?
Is there some flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: the slope of the tangent line indeed equals 1. Is there any reason why you think this cannot be the case?

Comment: I just don’t understand why the solution for the derivative of the quadratic equals the first coefficient on the linear function (mx -n).

Comment: I assume that since the derivative and the linear function belong to the same quadratic they can be equated: f’(x) = g(x) and then by equating the coefficients: 4x - 3 = m + n, we get the result m = 1, is that correct?

Comment: If we have a linear function $y=mx+c$, then $m$ is the slope of the line. In this case $f'(1)$ also gives the slope of the tangent line, so it equals 1

Comment: $f'(x)$ does not give the equation of the tangent line itself. $f'(x_0)$ gives the slope of the tangent line when $x=x_0$

Comment: I think I’m just not seeing something very elemental

Comment: The derivative of f(x) at any given point is defined as the slope of the tangent to f(x) at that given point. DO NOT confuse it to be the tangent line in itself.

Comment: So the solution of f’(x) cannot be equated to g(x) but it actually gives the value of m?

Comment: I see, think I got it, thank you very much

Comment: Yes, you are right. The first coefficient of g(x) is the slope of g(x). The derivative of f(x) is not equal to g(x), but again, the slope of g(x){at the given point}. That is why they are equal. g(x) is the tangent line to f(x) at the given point

Comment: Got it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The slope of the line $L(a)$ that is tangent to the graph of $f$ at $(a, f(a))$ is $f'(a).$ The slope of the line whose equation is $y=mx+n$ is $m,$ so if this line is $L(a)$ then $m=f'(a).$ In particular if $a=1$ and $f(a)=-3$ and $(a,f(a))=(1,-3)=A$ then  $m=f'(a)=f'(1)=1.$ Your reasoning is correct.